# What is the proper way to combine two different errors for the same measurement?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, statistics

We did an experiment in the lab (regarding magnetic domain walls) that yielded some pictures that we later on analyzed and manipulated in Matlab 
(we took an RGB image made it into grayscale one and than into BW. Afterwards we calculated the white pixels percentage out of the total number of pixels in the picture).

There are two main errors that we see using this method:
1) Some impurities and dust that were on the microscope slide (error of about 3%). What I mean by that is that I calculate 3% of white area when theoretically I should get 0% (all black).

2) The method described above isn't perfect and depending on the threshold values we choose in the Matlab functions we get another error source (error of about 8%). By that I mean that if you change the threshold a bit you get a different white area percentage by about an 8%.

My question is this, What is the proper way to combine this two independent errors? What will be the errorbar of such measurement?
My guess is that summing the percentage isn't the right way to handle it.

An example to clarify even further. Lets say I take a picture, run it through this process and get 56% of white area. I know that I have a 3% error from dust and an 8% error from Matlab. Should the final value (with an errorbar) be 56% $\pm$ 11% or should I take the two errors into account in a different manner?

Thanks a lot! :D
[image: An example of the described process on one picture.]

Comment: is the dust a 3% error, or a correction? If you apply the correction, the you have to estimate the error on that.

Comment: @JEB the 3% is the value I get when I should get a 0% reading (it's 3% of white area when theoretically there should be none). The 8% is also an estimated 8% of white area. I will edit my post to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the dusty slides, that's a systematic error for which you should correct by calibrating the instrument. So you measure a white pixel percentage, $P_0$, you can correct it by:

$$ P_1 = \alpha_d P_0 $$

where

$$\alpha_d = 1/(1-0.03)= 1.031$$

is the dust correction factor.

That's a systematic correction, not an error. The question is then, what is the uncertainty of $\alpha_d$? If the dust is random, you can take 10 measurements of the same thing and get a standard deviation, which is then the uncertainty of the correction factor, $\Delta \alpha_d$. If the dust is fixed, then it may correlate with the pattern and lead to systematic biases which depend on what you're trying to measure.

I'm not sure I understand the source of your MatLab correction:

$$ \alpha_{MatLab} = 1/(1-0.08)= 1.087 $$

Assuming it is an result of the algorithm (sampling and so forth), you can put in known simulated results into the algorithm and see what comes out. From that you can get a correction factor and an uncertainty (based again on the standard deviation of observed correction factors).

Combine the results via:

$$ P = \alpha P_0 $$

where

$$ \alpha = \alpha_{MatLab}\alpha_d  $$

is the total correction factor.

Then $$\Delta P = \Delta \alpha P_0 $$

where $\Delta\alpha$ is computed by combining the uncertainties in the standard fashion.

Answer (score 0):

[This document](http://ipl.physics.harvard.edu/wp-uploads/2013/03/PS3_Error_Propagation_sp13.pdf) nicely summarizes how to handle errors from multiple sources (called error propagation). Basically it allows you to calculate the error on $f(a,b)$ when you know the errors on $a$ and $b$. What exactly you need to do depends on the equations and formulas you are using (how $f$ depends on $a$ and $b$), but the link goes through most common cases ($a+b$, $a/b$, and so on). In your case the challenge might be to assign these numerical errors to specific parameters in your equations, but once that is done, the link should lead you the rest of the way.

Comment: Hey @Codename 47, thanks for your quick response. I think my original question wasn't clear enough. I have edited it and added an example. I don't have an equation to base my error calculations on. I just want to estimate the white area and take the both error sources into account.